# ") Syntax error Invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "

Tags: shell-script, arithmetic

I have commands in a `bash` script getting data from a source text file and then adding the value of a variable to it and using it in an if/else condition.

Source data file (`db_count.ini`) (Note: contains a space at the inside the double quotes):

```
db_ctdy_sr=" 7"
```

Script:

```
source db_count.ini

# Removing the whitespace on the stored data
n_db_sr=${db_ctdy_sr// /}

# Sum
c=0
b=7

echo "Value of db:"$n_db_sr

sm=$((n_db_sr + c))

echo "The value of db:"
echo "$sm" 
echo $sm 

if [ "$sm" = "$b" ]
then
   echo "Success."
else
   echo "Not."
fi

echo "Bye!"
```

But when I run the script it always me this

```
The value of db:7
") Syntax error Invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
The value of:


Not.
Bye!
```

Any tips? Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I can only get close to your error when I mangle the `db_ctdy_sr` assignment, for example: `db_ctdy_sr=" 7\""` -- can you confirm the exact syntax that db_count.ini is using?

Comment: @JeffSchaller, check my post again sir I had update some of the codes changing `$a` to `$sm`

Comment: @JeffSchaller , Inside the db_count.ini you can see a variable named `db_ctdy_sr=" 7"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your script is working here. The only way to make it produce the same error you report is to make the variable `db_ctdy_sr` contain a `new line`:

Add a new line:

```
source db_count.ini
db_ctdy_sr=$' 7\r'
```

And then test the script:

```
$ ./so

Value of db:7
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
The value of db:
 //test if working
//test if working
Not.
Bye!
```

That could happen if the file `db_count.ini` contains DOS carriage return characters.

Execute:

```
$ sed -n l db_count.ini
db_ctdy_sr= 7\r$
```

(or similar) to see the `\r` in the file.

remove carriage returns by editing the file and removing the failing characters, or by changing this line:

```
n_db_sr=${db_ctdy_sr// /}
```

To:

```
n_db_sr=${db_ctdy_sr//[ $'\r'}]}
```

Or, more general to remove all control characters:

```
n_db_sr=${db_ctdy_sr//[ $'\001'-$'\037']}
```

To make sure the collating order will not modify the intended order of ascii values from 1 (octal 001) to 31 (octal 037), set the bash variable:

```
shopt -s globasciiranges
```

Available since bash version 4.3.

Comment: CR is decimal 13 but octal `$'\015'` or hex `$'\xD'` -- and bash `$' '` also supports more convenient `\r`.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Yes, you are right; thanks, included.